# Special characters to mass replace string using sed command

Tags: php, regex, linux, sed, find

I want to replace a function with another function inside all php files. Below is how far i reached:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i s/check_perm(\'venA\')/check_perm(\'venA:venB\')/` {} \;
```

But gave me an error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.'

I want to replace `check_perm('venA')` with `check_perm('venA:venB')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i "s/check_perm('venA')/check_perm('venA:venB')/g" {} \;
```

tested with `GNU sed version 4.2.1`